# Show local html page with separate javascript file in a tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs, firefox-addon

I have a simple addon that adds a button to toolbar.

I want this toolbar to open a tab that shows a local html page that uses javascript to fetch some urls, process data and then display things on screen based on that data. I want this to happen on usual browser tab, not some extension window.

I want the extension to be portable on multiple platforms (by using html file and javascript) so I want just to have a tab with the html page that accesses javascript file on the same directory.

I use this on my button that opens the tab:

```
var win = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
  .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
  .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
  .rootTreeItem
  .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
  .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);

var tab = win.gBrowser.addTab();
win.gBrowser.selectedTab = tab;
```

What should I add after this to show a local, extension packaged (I have no idea where to package it) html page that will access a separate javascript file.

(this might be a very simple question but mozilla documentation is a gigantic mess with old information that doesn't work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your fancy tricks with `nsIInterfaceRequestor` seem to be unnecessary - it's a very complicated way of writing:

```
var win = window;
```

What you wrote there is necessary to get from a content page to the browser window - normal `window.top` won't work because of a security boundary between content and chrome. But your button *already is* in the browser window.

Since you already have a button - you must be using an overlay meaning that you registered a `chrome://` namespace. To open your page you can use [`loadOneTab` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Method/loadOneTab) (this has the advantage that you don't need to select the tab explicitly):

```
window.gBrowser.loadOneTab("chrome://myextension/content/page.html", {inBackground: false});
```

Of course you should change `myextension` here, it should be your chrome namespace. `page.html` should be put into the same directory where you have your overlay (typically `chrome/content/`). You can just use the regular script tag to load JavaScript files located in the same directory:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I just copied it from some document and it was the only thing I got working - I have been fighting with mozilla for quite some time now as the documentation is what it is.. I tried the relative chrome url before and it didn't work for some who knows why reason, now it did (?). So thank you, this solves the issue and thank you for the simplification for the window command.